# Putting a program in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, webbrowser-control

Just finishing up a program that some very helpful people on this site have advised me on.  The program grabs a user name from a list box, uses webBrowser control to enter the proper URL and then posts a message.  Now I want to put this on auto pilot and let is go through the list of names programmatically.  Where can I and how do I add the loop?

```
    private bool WaitingForData;
    public void master()
    {
        listBox();
        Application.DoEvents();

        GetData();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    public void listBox()//Handles getting names from ListBox
    {
        //load names to listbox
    }

    private void GetData()
    {  
        webBrowser1.Navigate(inputURLID);

        WaitingForData = true;
    }

    private void SendData()
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("subject").SetAttribute("value",        textBox2_Subject.Text);//To (username)

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("message").SetAttribute("value", richTextBox1.Text);//Subject

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Submit").InvokeMember("click");//Message
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WaitingForData) SendData();
        WaitingForData = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to automate this to work with a list of user names, there are two basic possibilities.

1) You wish to launch a UI, let someone manually add a comma or newline separated list of names, and then press a go button
2) You wish to get a list of names from a database/ web service or regularly replaced text file and for the program to automatically execute when there is new information to work with.

Lets address each in turn

1) You need to retrieve data from your list box and split it into a list of usernames. If you used comma separated values (e.g. `"Paul, Steve, Michael"`) you could split them using

`var names = myListBox.Text.Split(',');`

And then loop through them to do work with code similar to:

`foreach(var name in names)
{
    doWork(name);
}`

In option 2, you need a different style of program, either a windows service or a command line application running with Task Scheduler.

In either case, I'm not sure that the current structure of your program really lends itself to batch processing.

As a final note, if what you are trying to do is automate posting of email messages through a browser based client (which is what it looks like), then firstly this is a really bad idea, particularly using a web browser control to do this, and two, please ensure that you have a legitimate right to do so, as spamming a site like this is very detrimental if unchecked.

Comment: Ah, I missed the series of names part. Yeah, I would read those names from a database, then.

Comment: Thank you Sean and Paul.  I'll give Option 1 a try.  The task scheduler is a really good idea and I have used it before, I just don't think it would work here, because of the name list issue.  FYI, I am NOT a spammer, just coding for fun.  I thought I asked a good question, not sure why people marked it down?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the entire program in a "loop", the best way to do it would be through the Windows Task Scheduler. Just set up a task that points at the program, and set it to run however often you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx